# Google Tag Manager error with loadContainerPreferNonDefault JSONArray not supported

Tags: android, json, android-studio, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When calling

```
PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_json);
```

I get the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: JSONArrays are not supported

For the analytics library I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0

Now when I edit the gtm_json file to remove all the JSON Arrays, it works fine, but obviously we don't want to do that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Exported a binary file instead of a JSON file with the GTM dashboard to get around the issue. This is something that should still be solved though. It doesn't help that the documentation for the Google Tag Manager API is inconsistent in terms of what arguments can be passed (3rd argument can't be a boolean). https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/TagManager

Answer (score 2):

The container is not published yet so **Download** is not enabled.
[image]

**Export** is NOT the correct method, it creates a JSON file that is primarily used to copy configurations within the tag manager GUI.

With a published mobile container you will have the **Download** option.
Using the downloaded file the issue will be gone.

Comment: I get "Failed to extract the container from the resource file. Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container" when using the downloaded container.

I.e. it doesn't load exported with "java.lang.RuntimeException: JSONArrays are not supported" message and does't load downloaded with "Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container".